# How to know whether the column includes string?

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file that is something like as below.

```
SNP Beta A1 A2 P
rs124 -0.5 T C 0.11
rs534 0.22 A G 0.245
rs199 1.32 G C 0.345
rs947 -0.07 T G 0.00002
rs667 0.37 C T 0.04
....
```

There are 23640021 lines.
I conducted an analysis, which resulted in error as below.

```
WARNING: 255837 SNPs had P outside of (0,1]. The P column may mislabeled.
```

```
head -10000 file
```

The first and last 10000 lines did not includes any numbers outside of 0-1. So how can I figure out whether the column of P included something else?

Comment: do you mean, how to check the column p is greater than 1 ? or it contains any non-numeric characters ?

Comment: I meant both. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk command will check whether the last column value is >1 or it contains any other characters (except numbers and dot)

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && ($NF>1 || $NF~/[^0-9.]/)' test.txt
rs534 0.22 A G 0.245B
rs947 -0.07 T G 1.00002
rs667 0.37 C T 0.0A4

$ cat test.txt
SNP Beta A1 A2 P
rs124 -0.5 T C 0.11
rs534 0.22 A G 0.245B
rs199 1.32 G C 0.345
rs947 -0.07 T G 1.00002
rs667 0.37 C T 0.0A4
rs667 0.37 C T 0.04
```

Comment: MIght be useful to include the offending line numbers in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message seems to indicate a "clopen set" (open on the "left" side, closed on the "right") NOT including the 0. Try this apadtion of Kamaraj's fine proposal:

```
awk 'NR>1 && ($NF>1 || $NF~/[^0-9.]/ || $NF == 0)' file
```